# How to pass value in c#.net on LinkButton event within a dataList.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have been designing a code for a project, where I want to get the "ProductId" on  `OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"` event.

**Here is the code:**

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr><td><%#Eval("ProductId")%>

           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
   <img src='<%#Eval("Image")%>' style="width: 220px; height: 146px" alt="" />
                                            </asp:LinkButton></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                                <%#Eval("ArtName")%>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                                <%#Eval("Price")%>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
```

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OnItemCommand event on your DataList`

And try with `CommandArgument` and `CommandName`

```
void Item_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
      {
           if(e.CommandName ="Select")
           {
              var e = e.CommandArgument;
              .... 
           }

      }
```

View :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductId")%>' />
```

Note : Add OnItemCommand on your datalist

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the itemcommand pattern.

An example at :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Basically, you can :

- dismiss the OnClick on your LinkButton
- set a CommandName (for example "LBClick") and CommandArgument (your value) on your button
- subscribe to the DataLIst ItemCommand event
- handle your button click in the ItemCommand handler (if e.CommandName == "LBClick", run code with e.CommandArgument as value)

Hope this will help