# How to get url for linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, onclick

I have a DataList, which are loaded in the search results(url, description, title). I need to know URL for which the user click on the search results. I do this using linkbutton. But OnClick handler can't call, if I using PostBackUrl property in LinkButton Control.

```
//Default.aspx
    <asp:Panel ID="panResults" runat="server" Height="236px">
        <p style="text-align: left" align="left"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal" Font-Bold="true" /></p>
        <asp:DataList ID="dlstResults" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" OnItemDataBound="DataList_ItemDataBound" >
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResultUrl" runat="server" OnClick="Link_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url") %>'
                    PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblResultUrl" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"
                    Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblResultSummay" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>     
        </asp:DataList>   
    </asp:Panel>

//Code-behind
protected void Link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);       
    string myValue = btn.CommandArgument;
}
```

Comment: Link button supports the command argument and command name attributes

Comment: @Steve, And what does that mean? In my example I use the CommandArgument. But this is not working, If I put in PostBackUrl.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand(v=vs.80).aspx      handle this event, throw the url for each in the command argument attribute (which you're doing), give it a command name so you know which control its from in the event handler.

Comment: I don't have the motivation to write this up in a pretty little answer, but it gives you some direction. This shows how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431710/how-to-pass-value-in-c-net-on-linkbutton-event-within-a-datalist

Comment: @Steve, I read your links, but I don't understand how to do that. Please help.

Comment: try my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tell your DataList that everytime something happens (something is clicked on, or changed) in the controls in your DataList to call the method `dlstResults_ItemCommand`.

You accomplish this by placing the attribute `OnItemCommand="dlstResults_ItemCommand"` in your DataList.

Then you build the method that you typed in the above attribute. In this case its called `dlstResults_ItemCommand`. Then in there you check which control raised the event by checking the command name (This is an attribute placed by your CommandArgument attribute). If its the right control, pull out the commandargument and thats your url.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlstResults" runat="server" CellPadding="4" OnItemCommand="dlstResults_ItemCommand"
        ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" OnItemDataBound="DataList_ItemDataBound" >
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResultUrl" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url") %>' CommandName="SomeName"
                %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblResultUrl" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"
                Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblResultSummay" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>     
    </asp:DataList> 


protected void dlstResults_ItemCommand(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
{
   if(e.CommandName ="SomeName")
   {
      string url = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
         //url now holds the url of the clicked on link
   }

}
```

Comment: @HelioGracie hmmm... are you rebinding the datalist on page_load? throw it in a !Page.IsPostBack conditional.... if that doesn't work try manually linking the event to the event handler in your designer (or hell, even page load might work)

Comment: I put databind method in IsPostBack condition, but don't help.

Comment: @HelioGracie no, !IsPostBack, you want to negate it... you dont want the datalist re-bind on post backs, only on the initial load.

Comment: ItemCommand event not firing maybe because of the `PostBackUrl` in linkbutton. You can try to remove it and use `Response.Redirect` in code behind `Response.Redirect("//" + url);`

Comment: @Steve and Emre thanks a lot. Emre I removed PostBackUrl argument from LinkButton and use Response.Redirect this is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Response.Redirect in your code-behind and remove PostBackUrl from your linkbutton

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlstResults" runat="server" CellPadding="4" OnItemCommand="dlstResults_ItemCommand"
    ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" OnItemDataBound="dlstResults_ItemDataBound">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResultUrl" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url") %>'
            CommandName="SomeName" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblResultUrl" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblResultSummay" runat="server" Text="desc" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and code-behind

```
protected void dlstResults_ItemCommand(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "SomeName")
    {
        string url = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        //do some stuff with url before you redirect
        Response.Redirect("//" + url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice attempt! Unfortunately, getting a link button to raise the OnClick event from within a DataList or GridView row doesn't work. Kind of counter-intuitive, I know :)

Comment: oh.. didnt know that, rowcommand/itemcommand is the right way like in your answer, but does postbackurl + itemcommand work together? just curious :)

Comment: Ah, you caught the postbackurl quickly! I overlooked this comment yesterday. +1