# C# DataList in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am making a web application which allow students to post problem or ideas
I am using datalist having some labels and button inside now I want to pick the post_id on clicking "approve" button (button is in datalist) ? how can I do this ?

Comment: check 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431710/how-to-pass-value-in-c-net-on-linkbutton-event-within-a-datalist)

Comment: Please add some code to help other understand the problem. Care about spelling ie dots are missing . Supposing you have the identity field as id it should look like as follows
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Post" OnClick="btn_Click" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'/>

Comment: Everything is well onclick event is working but i am not able to get the text from label on clicking a button...

Answer (score 0):

You will take a bool type variable and assign `false` by default. when you change this bit value from `false` to `true`. Then you can show `tick` on the basis of that bit.

Comment: I don't want to know which button is pressed .... I jus t want to get the Post Id on clicking a button.... I.e. text from label

Comment: Ok ok I understand. For this purpose you will have to make an `click event` and pass it `post_id` on each post while rendering the post on the View. Whenever you trigger that click event you get an post_id